# Firebase/Ionic: Type 'UserCredential' is not assignable to type 'User'. Property 'delete' is missing in type 'UserCredential'

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I recently just start learning about the Ionic and Firebase and follow the tutorial on Pluralsight "Authenticating Users with Firebase Authentication Service Playbook". I face an error that I think maybe is a version of one Ionic or Firebase outdated but after google I still no idea how to solved this.

**AuthProvider**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';

@Injectable()
export class AuthProvider {

  constructor() {

  }

  async signUpUser(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const newUser:User = await firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

      await firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${newUser.uid}`)
          .set({email:email, firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName});
        return newUser;
    } catch (error){
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

It throw error of "Type 'UserCredential' is not assignable to type 'User'.
  Property 'delete' is missing in type 'UserCredential'. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem due to some backwards compatibility issue with your  import statement

```
import {User} from '@firebase/auth-types';
```

Solution 1)

a)
Modify your "firebase" entry inside package.json by:
"firebase": "4.10.0"

b)
Delete node_modules folder

c)
run npm install.

Solution 2)

```
  signUpUser(
    email: string,
    password: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string
  ) {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function(userRecord) {
        firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${userRecord.uid}`)
          .set({ email: email, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName });
        return userRecord;
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        throw error;
      });
  }
```